# Is it a correct use of "voice over"?

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs

> The voice actors voiced over the puppets as they moved their mouths.

I feel it's not the correct phrasal verb, but I can't think of a way to correctly express this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "voice over" is more like an "aside", that is, a narration that is separate from dialog.

[Merriam-Webster "voice-over"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/voice-over)
1a : the voice of an unseen narrator speaking (as in a motion picture or television commercial)
b : the voice of a visible character (as in a motion picture) expressing unspoken thoughts

For your use, you might say that "the voice actors voiced/spoke the puppets' lines as their mouths were moved."